# Unable to process scss with svelte-image

Tags: sass, svelte, svelte-3

I would like to use scss with svelte and svelte-image but I got an error
(without svelte-image, everything works well)

the error:

```sh
CompileError [ParseError]: Colon is expected

code: 'css-syntax-error',
  start: { line: 26, column: 6, character: 394 },
  end: { line: 26, column: 6, character: 394 },
  pos: 394,
  filename: undefined,
  frame: '24:     z-index: 99;\n' +
    '25: \n' +
    '26:     img {\n' +
    '            ^\n' +
    '27:       width: 100%;\n' +
    '28:       height: auto;'
```

here is my rollup config

```js
import svelte from "rollup-plugin-svelte";
...

import scss from "rollup-plugin-scss";
import sveltePreprocess from "svelte-preprocess";
import image from "svelte-image";

...

export default {
  ...

  plugins: [
    svelte({
      preprocess: [
        sveltePreprocess({
          scss: {
            includePaths: ["src"],
          },
          postcss: {
            plugins: [require("autoprefixer")],
          },
        }),

        image({
          optimizeAll: true,
          publicDir: "./public/",
          quality: 80,
        }),
      ],
      compilerOptions: {
        // enable run-time checks when not in production
        dev: !production,
      },
    }),

    scss({
      output: "./public/build/bundle.css",
    }),

    ...

  ],
};
```

I think it comes from the preprocessor order (markup then script then style)

Should I add the style into separated scss?

Answer (score 1):

You have to run preprocessors sequentially because svelte-image uses svelte.parse() internally, so svelte-preprocess needs to be run before if any scss is present.

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-sequential-preprocessor and do something like this:

```
svelte({
  preprocess: seqPreprocessor([ autoPreprocess(), image() ])
})
```

Comment: Thank you, I will check this soon :)